# Maven build fail - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli

Tags: maven

I installed Maven and TeamCity on a Ubuntu server VM and I'm cannot build a project (threadfix) on TeamCity (also tried with Jenkins).

The output is a Java error:

```
/usr/lib/apache-maven/maven/bin/mvn: 1: /usr/lib/apache-maven/maven/bin/mvn: uname:not found    
/usr/lib/apache-maven/maven/bin/mvn: 1: /usr/lib/apache-maven/maven/bin/mvn: dirname: not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getMainClass(Launcher.java:145)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:267)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)                                                    
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)                                          
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[WARNING] Build command mvn package exited with code 100. Please verify that the build completed successfully.
```

It was failing due org.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher was missing, so I download from java2s and the error message changed for this (there was also messages about conf/logging and m2.conf, but after moving those files, they dissappeared and the current error is this one.

I already configured the environment variables as

```
PATH="/usr/lib/apache-maven/maven/bin..."
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
M2_HOME="/usr/lib/apache-maven/maven"
```

The directories apparently are correct and I also configured the same environment variables on TeamCity.

I also checked and the lib/ is not empty.

I downloads the binary release from the official Maven website, 3.5.2, reinstalled, uninstalled, installed 3.5.0, but all of them I'd ran into the same issue.

The build command I'm using is:

```
cov-build --dir intDir/ mvn package
```

If I build this from the command line on Ubuntu, it builds successfully, the only issue is when trying to build from TeamCity or Jenkins.

Can someone please help me? I'm new to this world of Maven/TeamCity/Jenkins...

Thanks!